# How to calculate combined random and fixed effect BLUPs for rma.mv in metafor?

Tags: r, metafor

In the meta-analysis package metafor in R, there is a blup() function for rma.uni() but not rma.mv(). I have an rma.mv model with a random intercept term. If I use:

```
predict.rma(model,transf=exp)
```

then I get an estimate from my fixed effect moderators for each datapoint in my original dataset, and:

```
ranef(model,transf=exp)
```

gives me predictions for each level of my random effect.

Is there then a way to combine the information from these two functions to get combined random and fixed effect BLUPs, as would be provided by the blup() function?

(I have tried taking the mean of both the fixed effect estimate and the random effect prediction for each datapoint in my original dataset, and this *looks* right when I plot it ... but surely it's not that simple?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add (don't take the mean) what `predict()` gives you to what `ranef()` gives you, but you have to be careful in correctly 'lining up' the BLUPs with the rows from `predict()`. The row names from `ranef()` tell you the levels for which the BLUPs are computed, so you can use them to match things up correctly. Also, first add them, then you can exponentiate the values, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks! Yep I think was the order I was exponentiating things in that seemed to be making the mean look more sensible than the sum. Figured it out now thanks to your answer and posted some code below.

Answer (score 1):

In the process of following Wolfgang's very helpful instructions in the marked answer, I created some code to do this with an example dataset. Posting in case it helps anyone else:

**Update:** following Wolfgang's comment below, I have removed the code for the CIs and replaced it with code to calculate the SE for the BLUP.

```
#load packages and example data    
library(metafor)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat<-dat.konstantopoulos2011
dat

#make a model - note I have nested random effects
#(no idea if it actually makes sense with this example dataset!)
mod<-rma.mv(yi,vi,mods=~year,random=~1|district/school,data=dat)

#predict from the model (without exponentiating) and attach to original data
preds<-predict.rma(mod,addx=TRUE)
dat$pred<-preds$pred
dat$ci.ub<-preds$ci.ub
dat$ci.lb<-preds$ci.lb
dat$fe_se<-preds$se
dat$dist.sch<-interaction(dat$district,dat$school) #create a label for each district/school

#get the district random effects and label them
dist_re<-data.frame(ranef(mod)$district)
dist_re$district<-rownames(dist_re)

#get the school random effects and label them
sch_re<-data.frame(ranef(mod)$`district/school`)
sch_re$dist.sch<-rownames(sch_re)
sch_re$dist.sch<-gsub("/",".",sch_re$dist.sch)
colnames(sch_re)<-c("intrcpt2","se2","pi.lb2","pi.ub2","dist.sch") #to avoid duplicate colnames later

#join the district and school random effects to the data by labels
plotdat<-join(dat,dist_re,by="district")
plotdat2<-join(plotdat,sch_re,by="dist.sch")

#create the blups and intervals by adding the fixed effect estimates and random effect predictions,
#and exponentiating:
plotdat2$blup<-exp(plotdat2$pred+plotdat2$intrcpt+plotdat2$intrcpt2)
plotdat2$blup.se<-sqrt((plotdat2$fe_se^2)+(plotdat2$se^2)+(plotdat2$se2^2))

#forest plot of BLUPs and their SEs just to check they make sense:
ggplot(plotdat2, aes(y=dist.sch, x=blup, xmin=blup-blup.se, xmax=blup+blup.se))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbarh(height=.2)+
  ylab('District and school')+
  geom_vline(xintercept=1,linetype='dashed')+
  xlim(0,5)+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: I don't think that you can add up the CI bounds like you did. If anything, you would want to add up the squared SEs from `predict()` and `ranef()` (i.e., the variances) and then take the square root of that sum to get the SEs of the BLUPs based on which you can then compute the CIs. However, I don't know off the top of my head whether the fitted values and predicted random effects are independent (if not, one would also need to know their covariances to construct the CIs).

Comment: Oops yes that was a bit optimistic of me. I have removed that and just calculated the SE to avoid getting into the technicalities of the CIs.