# Predictions from rma.mv in metafor not aligning with data distribution or BLUPs

Tags: metafor

My colleagues and I are running a mixed effects meta-analysis model using `rma.mv()` in `metafor` and we are confused about why the predictions we obtain seem very off-centred compared to our data.

We have multiple observations from most studies in our dataset, so have included 'studyID' as a random term. We have one fixed term, a factor with four levels. Below is a plot with predictions obtained from a model using the following script:

```
## run model
mod <- rma.mv(yi ~ factor, random = ~ studyID, V=vi, data = data, method="REML")

## extract unique dummy variables for each level of factor
pred_dat <- data.frame(mod$data[,c("factor")], model.matrix(mod)[,-1])
pred_dat <- unique(pred_dat)

## generate predictions
preds <- predict.rma(mod, newmods = as.matrix(pred_dat[,-1]))
preds$factor <- pred_dat[,1]
```

The plot shows the prediction for each level of the factor (in black) overlaid on the raw data (yi; coloured points). The colour scale relates to the variance of each point (vi), with darker points having a lower variance and so presumably a higher weight. The dark grey circles are the BLUPs (i.e. random estimate for each studyID + fixed estimate for each factor level) generated according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630647/how-to-calculate-combined-random-and-fixed-effect-blups-for-rma-mv-in-metafor):

[image: a plot of rma.mv predictions, BLUPs, and underlying data]

**The issue is that the predictions (black dots) for level 2 and to a lesser extent for level 3 seem rather off-centre in relation to both the BLUPs (grey circles) and underlying data (coloured points), and we don't understand why.** We are happy if the results are correct, but we would like to be able to explain the discrepancy to readers/reviewers (or of course if we have done something wrong we would like to fix it).

It seems to be something to do with the random term, because if we run the model just using `rma()` without the random term, then the plot looks like this (this time with no BLUPs or colour scale):

[image: a plot of rma predictions and underlying data]

*Maybe* it's something to do with the how the random term affects the weight for each study or observation? (I tried to follow along with the explanation on [this page on the metafor website](https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:weights_in_rma.mv_models) but the example script does not work when there is a fixed term included)

I have tried and failed to reproduce this issue on a simple example dataset, so I assume it's something to do with the peculiarities of our large dataset... any advice or insight will be much appreciated!

**Update:** My colleague has been exploring further and found the issue seems to be largely caused by the few studies we have that contribute data to multiple levels of the factor (most studies fall within one level). If he removes studies with multiple levels the issue disappears. Could these few studies be having an outsized effect?